# Objective C, Convert BASE64String to HEX

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, base64

i tried to convert Base64String to Hexa
after i look for documentation, i didn't find any clue
so i decided to convert Base64String to NSData
Then Convert NSData to Hex

but when i check with Base64String Online Encoder, it fail

then i found someone post this code

```
    NSMutableString *hex = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
      [hex appendFormat:@"%02x", base64String[i]];
```

but again, it's fail when convert back to Base64String

Am I in the right track?

Answer (score 0):

i end up using this libarary

https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity

with old way, convert to NSData then convert to Hex